# I want to make a temperature controller, but the heating element didn't work

Tags: mosfet, controller

My schematic circuit from controller to heater (12V)

[image: schematic]

When I connect the heater, the voltage drops to zero.

When I try it in a simulator with a DC motor, it works:

[image: simulator]

This is my 12V heating element:

[image: heating element]

Comment: From your schematic it doesn't look like there any current is possible through the heater.

Comment: Where is the 12V coming from, and how is it connected to the heater? You've left out a lot of important details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this: -

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't connect the controller output to +12V.

Comment: @PeterBennett I was just fixing it (twice!).

Comment: Ok , the 12 V is just the heater specification to heat up, so how to make the right circuit for the heater  to work?

Comment: You need a 12 volt DC supply as shown in my answer as per your modified circuit @谢RenS

Comment: Ok , i will try it , for the mosfet i use n channel , will it work?

Comment: You need to use an N channel MOSFET that is rated to handle the current of the heater.